# Why kafka streams state dir is in /tmp/kafka-streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I'm not sure if it's already answered. As I didn't get proper explanation, posting my question here.

Why kafka streams `state.dir` is stored under `/tmp/kafka-streams`?

I know I can change the path by providing the state dir config in the stream code like below

`StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG,"/var/abc-Streams"`

But will there be any impact of changing the directory?

or

Can I configure the state DB in an application directory and not in `/tmp`.

As per the confluent documentation, for :
`Stateful` operations :

`automatically creates and manages such state stores when you are calling stateful operators such as count() or aggregate(), or when you are windowing a stream`

but didn't specify where exactly it's being stored.

ANy thoughts?

Comment: @cricket_007: Any thoughts on the consequences of changing the state store directory? In my case, just today I changed it and weirdly all messages flew downstream! E.g. Given from topic A -> aggregate(..) -> to topic B, all events were again produced to topic B, but not re-consumed from A.

Answer (score 9):

> Why kafka streams state.dir is stored under /tmp/kafka-streams?

There are several reasons.

1. Usually `/tmp` directory has a default write permission. So you don't have to struggle with write permissions as a beginner.
2. `/tmp` directory is short lived directory. On each system reboot, it is cleaned, hence you don't experience the over flooded disk storage in case you forgot to delete the `state.dir`. Downside is, you lose the states from previous run hence you need to rebuild the states from scratch.

If you want to reuse the states stored in `state.dir`, you should store it somewhere except `/tmp`.

All the state-stores are stored in the location specified in `state.dir`. If not specified, it is `/tmp/kafka-streams/<app-id>` directory.